# Unable to connect to sts endpoint url

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have setup EKS cluster and have configured the OIDC. I have then created the IAM role with the below trust relationship

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/55A76A4197643C67E88FD47738722195"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/55A76A4197643C67E88FD47738722195:sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:aws-test",
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/55A76A4197643C67E88FD47738722195:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use the service account in the pod, and from within the Pod, when I run the `aws s3 ls`, I am getting the below error:

`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"`

How to troubleshoot this error

Comment: Is STS endpoint enabled for ap-south-1 region? You can check it from the IAM console and selecting Account settings from the navigation pane.

Comment: How to check under the account settings?